# Display User Information on Main Form after Login using C# Windows form & SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication

[Login with Username & Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl2cj.png)
[Showing Username in Home window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Y2b.png)
[Database Schema (I am not showing table value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flRvG.png)

But In my Database, I added a column name "Display_Name" & enter this column value by sql insert query. I am able to show Username to Homepage.

Code:

```
        string Username = textBox1.Text;
        string Password = textBox2.Text;           

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 192.168.105.30; Initial Catalog = testDB; User ID = sa; Password = 123456");
        connection.Open();

        string sqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Coke_User WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);

        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);

        int count = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();

        if (count > 0)
        {
            UserName.Name = "Hello " + @Username + ", Welcome to COKE.";

            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered wrong credentials!");
        }
}
```

I want to show Display_Name against Username. That means It will show the Display_Name of the user who will login with that username.

Comment: I have added 3 screenshoots

Comment: _Do not persist passwords_. Ever. No. Just don't. Not even ...

Comment: `string Password = textBox2.Text;` followed by `Password=@Password` is *very* concerning. YOur are most certainly storing *plain text* passwords in your database; that is a severe security vulnerability for you and your users. *Always* hash and salt stored passwords. **Always**.

Comment: Thnaks, it's working. Can you share a project link in your, that fullfill bunch issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the `Display_Name` instead of `COUNT(*)`, and check for `null` to make sure the user actually exists.

You have a bunch of other issues

- The connection and command (and reader if you use one) need to be disposed with `using`.
- Do not use `AddWithValue`, instead specify the exact parameter type and length/precision.
- Do not store plain-text passwords. Instead salt-and-hash them, and store as a byte array.
- Do not hardcode the connection string. Instead use a settings file.
- Do not use IP addresses to connect to SQL Server, instead use a DNS name.
- Preferably do not use `sa`, instead create a more limited user in SQL Server.
- Consider using `await connection.OpenAsync();` and `await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync();` in order to keep the UI responsive.

  ```
    string Username = textBox1.Text;
    string Password = textBox2.Text;           

    using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    const string sqlQuery = @"
    SELECT Display_Name
    FROM Coke_User
    WHERE Username = @Username
      AND PasswordHash = @PasswordHash;
    ";
    using SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbtype.NVarChar, 100).Value = Username;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@PasswordHash", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 64).Value = SaltAndHash(Password, UserName);

    connection.Open();
    int displayName = (string)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();

    if (displayName != null)
    {
        UserName.Name = $"Hello {DisplayName}, Welcome to COKE.";
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered wrong credentials!");
    }
  ```